# Below code works fine with function declaration but not with function expression

Tags: javascript

I am writing two type of code in javascript one is with function declaration and  one with function expression i just wrote first with function declaration for createDrinkorder function and second one with function expression and the problem i am facing is that i am getting correct output for function declaration but error with function expression and according to javascript rules i can use both function declaration and function expression but when i try to do the task with function expression i am getting error that createDrinkorder  is not a function

below is my code for that

```js
var passengers = [{
    name: "Jane Doloop",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Evel",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "Sue Property",
    paid: false,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "John Funcall",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  }
];

function servePassengers(passengers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
  }
}
servePassengers(passengers);

function createDrinkOrder(passenger) {
  if (passenger.ticket === "firstclass") {
    document.write("Would you like a cocktail or wine?" + "<br>");
  } else {
    document.write("Your choice is cola or water." + "<br>");
  }
}

function serveCustomer(passenger) {
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
}
```

and this is code for function expression

```js
var passengers = [{
    name: "Jane Doloop",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Evel",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "Sue Property",
    paid: false,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "John Funcall",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  }
];

function servePassengers(passengers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
  }
}
servePassengers(passengers);
var createDrinkOrder = function(passenger) {
  if (passenger.ticket === "firstclass") {
    document.write("Would you like a cocktail or wine?" + "<br>");
  } else {
    document.write("Your choice is cola or water." + "<br>");
  }
}

function serveCustomer(passenger) {
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
}
```

Comment: Because you call `servePassengers` which is *before* `createDrinkOrder` is created. So when `servePassengers` calls `serviceCustomer` and then that calls `createDrinkOrder`, the function hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Due to hoisting, functions hoisted at the top then the variables. This is where you get the issue...;)

Comment: but to check the same thimg i tried a simple code i first created a fumction and call another function in that and again anoher function expression in that and that was for just a simple printing a number that works fine but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your script the JavaScript interpreter jumbles some stuff around in your file. This is called *hoisting*. It literally means that parts of your script are *hoisted* to the top of the script. First come your function and variable declarations. Note that the variables have no assigned value on this point.

That leaves the top of your script looking like this:
**(This is what your browser is doing)**

```
function servePassengers(passengers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
  }
}

function serveCustomer(passenger) {
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
}

var passengers, createDrinkOrder;
```

The rest of your script, however, remains largely the same. Assignments and initializations stay in the same order. So, when reading from top to bottom, what happens is that first `passengers` gets assigned the array as value.

Then we go to the `servePassengers` initialization which in turn calls the `createDrinkOrder` through different callbacks. But `createDrinkOrder` does not have a value yet. That value is assigned after `servePassengers` is called.

```
// Passengers are assigned.
passengers = [{
    name: "Jane Doloop",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Evel",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "Sue Property",
    paid: false,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "John Funcall",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  }
];

// servePassengers is called, but at this point, createDrinkOrder does not
// have an assigned value yet.
servePassengers(passengers);

// Only after servePassengers does createDrinkOrder have a value.
createDrinkOrder = function(passenger) {
  if (passenger.ticket === "firstclass") {
    document.write("Would you like a cocktail or wine?" + "<br>");
  } else {
    document.write("Your choice is cola or water." + "<br>");
  }
}
```

So you are calling a variable with a function as value which is not **yet** there. It is so important to pay attention to the order and know what is happening behind the scenes in your browser. For example: `const` and `let` are not hoisted and have to be in the correct order from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the function `servePassengers` before `createDrinkOrder` declaration, `createDrinkOrder` do not exist when you call `serverPassengers`

try this

```
var passengers = [{
    name: "Jane Doloop",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Evel",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "Sue Property",
    paid: false,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "John Funcall",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  }
];

function servePassengers(passengers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
  }
}

var createDrinkOrder = function(passenger) {
  if (passenger.ticket === "firstclass") {
    document.write("Would you like a cocktail or wine?" + "<br>");
  } else {
    document.write("Your choice is cola or water." + "<br>");
  }
}

function serveCustomer(passenger) {
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
  createDrinkOrder(passenger);
}

servePassengers(passengers);
```